# Recently added new column in Hadoop "state_geocode" which populates data from substring (tax_geocode, 3, 3)

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, hadoop, hive

I inserted the data in new column and it looks fine. 
Now I want to copy the data from old table to new table(having same columns)
I copied the data but the data is not populating from pervious record 
I want to populate the data from previous record also for new column state_geocode

I can see my data in new columns county_geocode which I loaded a week ago, here my question is I want to copy and populate my data from old table to new table where the new column will be having all the data from last year also.

substr(tax_geocode, 3, 3) as county
_geocode

Comment: Could you add some of the code you wrote? And also some sample data and expected outputs? Enough to replicate the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: I have 3 columns  journal_posting_date=2019-11-13, tax_activity_date=2018-10-23 and load_month   and for 3rd column LOAD_MONTH I want output like 201911 if there is data on journal_posting_date ELSE i want 201810 if journal_posting_date is having no data

Comment: hive> INSERT INTO load_month_testing_2 (load_month)
    > SELECT CASE WHEN (`load_month_testing`.`journal_posting_date` IS NULL OR length(trim(`load_month_testing`.`journal_posting_date`)) < 1) THEN substr(`load_month_testing`.`tax_activity_date`, 1, 6) ELSE substr(`load_month_testing`.`journal_posting_date`, 1, 6)  END as `load_month`
    > FROM load_month_testing
    > ;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 2:80 Wrong arguments 'journal_posting_date': trim takes only STRING/CHAR/VARCHAR types. Found DATE
hive>